# Two Windows Store Applications in one Solution

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, monogame

We'd like to create many MonoGames inside one Visual Studio 2012 Solution. The main screen has to be a Windows Store Application. From the main menu, we'd be able to navigate to specified minigame and when it finishes, navigate back to main menu. Is it possible to create that? Is this project correct in Microsoft Windows Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple Windows Store apps (or projects) from one Visual Studio solution. Each project will have its own package file. However, they are separate apps and not related to each other. One alternative is to create one solution (or one Windows Store app) with multiple games. For example, you create one or a set of xaml pages for each game, and then navigate between these xaml pages. I know this approach works but just haven't tested it with MonoGame. For more info on packaging, check out [Packaging your Windows Store app using Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Zhiming is correct, you would need to have one main project. Because this is effectively XNA you can have multiple content projects to keep your assets separate, but all of the "games" have to be compiled into one package (think .exe for simplicity). There are lots of articles on how to have multiple levels or scenes in an XNA game. Follow one of those and treat each game as a new 'scene' or entry point from the main menu.

Comment: We've managed not to use Mono, and target on JS and HTML5, but thanks for answers :)